# How to add data to Cloud Firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The problem is that data is not inserted.

***Here is the node.js code :***

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var db = admin.firestore();
exports.signUp = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const uuid = data.uuid;
  const name = data.name;
  const gender = data.gender;
  const age = data.age;

  var docRef = db.collection('users').doc(uuid).set({
    name: name,
    gender: gender,
    age: age,
    current_point: 0,
    point_charging: 0,
    init_timestamp: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
    update_timestamp: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
  }).then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
    return;
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    return;
  });
});
```

***The log results of firebase functions :*** 
[image]

However, my database is still empty. I can not find my fault. Help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Self Answer***

I tried to insert data into the firestore via firebase functions on mobile, but I modified it to insert it directly in mobile. Inserting data through functions ... I don't know if it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it still helps. I was facing the same recently, and after reading various sources i was able to find the problem.

We have to wait for the action to complete from the firestore, as it has to handle to promise.

Using async and await solves the problem.

```
async function getFirestore(){

var my_var = await admin.firestore();

}
```