# Firebase cloud function won't insert into firestore

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add a document from a firebase cloud function to firestore, but it isn't working. This is what I'm doing:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin"
import * as functions from "firebase-functions"

admin.initializeApp()

exports.findDeck = functions.https.onCall((data: { deckId: string }) => {
    admin.firestore().collection("messages").add({original: "for me"})
    return requestDeck.findDeck(data.deckId)
})
```

Seems like it should be simple enough. I'm following an example here:

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/uppercase-firestore/functions/index.js

I've also tried following the firestore docs for Node.js, and using `set` instead of `add`. None of it does anything, or seems to report an error.

Comment: I answered with the most likely cause of the problem below. For future problems, always include the information that is written to the Cloud Functions logging panel, as it contains crucial information about the function invocation.

Comment: See my answer to same question in this thread. We have to use async and await. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58057457/8138641

Answer (score 0):

Adding a document to Cloud Firestore is an asynchronous operation. As you've written it now, there's a good chance that the function is terminated by its container before the document is added to Firestore.

To properly signal to Cloud Functions when your code is done, be sure to chain all promises from asynchronous operations:

```
exports.findDeck = functions.https.onCall((data: { deckId: string }) => {
    return admin.firestore().collection("messages").add({original: "for me"})
      .then(() => {
        return requestDeck.findDeck(data.deckId)
      });
})
```